# How to install nvgpu?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have to install DESC-Opt which is a special MHD equations solver for academic reasons and I just can't seem to install nvgpu... Also, I'm styding applied physics and come from a mechanical engineering backround, so I'm not that handy with code although we kinda used Python before. But here I just don't seem to see how to solve that.

Also, I'm running that on Windows 11

The source code is https://github.com/PlasmaControl/DESC

I pip installed the package with `pip install desc-opt` but always got an error.

I followed every installation step but I always get this stacktrace :

```
python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1

  [13 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\noliv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-13wmp7r3\nvgpu_829dd36c50e04507a88548d9ba9c5a7d\setup.py", line 33, in <module>
      long_description=read_file('README.md'),
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\noliv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-13wmp7r3\nvgpu_829dd36c50e04507a88548d9ba9c5a7d\setup.py", line 6, in read_file
      return f.read()
             ^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
      return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 4846: character maps to <undefined>
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

So I looked in the requirements;

```
colorama
h5py >= 3.0.0
jax[cpu] >= 0.2.11, <= 0.4.1
matplotlib >= 3.3.0, <= 3.6.0, != 3.4.3
mpmath >= 1.0.0
netcdf4 >= 1.5.4
numpy >= 1.20.0
nvgpu
psutil
scipy >= 1.5.0
termcolor
```

and installed every packages one by one and the issue seems to come from nvgpu that somehow won't install.

I looked and searched on the net and found that this error happens when The file doesn't using the right encoding. But I just can't figure out how to solve this issue. I read that I have to add an argument to the `f.read()` to specify which encoding the document has.

At this point I don't really know anymore, and I think I might need some help...

Thank you very much!

Comment: The metadata of nvgpu states that it is for Linux only. Your actual problem seems to come from an mismatch of the encodings of your terminal and the README.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try it on a linux machine at uni!